# Help with two calculus proofs

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

**Problem:** If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is of class $C^1$ and verifies:

I) $f( 1 , 2 ) < 0$

II) $(Q_n)_n$ is a sequence of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\lim _{n\to \infty}f(Q_{n})=+\infty$

Prove:

a) There is $ P\in \mathbb {R} ^{2}$ such that $f(P)=0$

b) If there are two points $P,Q\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(P)=f(Q)=0$, then there is $ R\in \mathbb {R} ^{2}$ such that $\nabla f(R)$ is orthogonal to the vector $P-Q.$

**Attempt of solution:**

a) If $\lim _{n\to \infty}f(Q_{n})=+\infty$, then it has to be a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ n_0<n$ and $f(Q_{n_0})>0$, because $f$ is $C^1$, therefore it's continuous in its whole domain (I'm really insecure with this part, I find it very vague).

Define a function $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, continuous in $[0,1]$,  where $\alpha(0)=(1,2)$ and $\alpha(1)=Q_{n_0}.$ Let's define the function $g(t)=f(\alpha(t))$, which is continuous for being a composition of continuous. Also $g(0)<0$ and $g(1)>0$, so I can apply Bolzano's theorem:

Let's call $S$ the set of the $x\in [0,1]$ where $g(x)<0. \quad S\ne \emptyset$ because at least $g(0)\in S$ and it's superior bounded for at least $g(1)$. Then, it must have a supremum. Let $s$ be the supremum of $S$. We can define the sequence $S_n$ where $g(S_n) \rightarrow s$, for S being bounded and closed. Then we have to see if $g(s)<0$ or $g(s)=0$. If $g(s)<0$ then there is an interval $(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)\cap [P,s]$ where $g(x)<0 \quad \forall$ x in that interval. Besides, $s<g(1)$ therefore there is a $\tilde{x}\in(s,s+\epsilon)$ such that $g(\tilde{x})<0$. But then $\tilde{x}\in S$ and $\tilde{x}>s$, and this can't be possible, because s is the supremum of the set. Then $g(s)=0$, and I take a $P=\alpha(s)$. QED.

b) I don't really know where to start here. I think it has something to do with Rolle's Theorem, which I could apply doing something similar to what I have done with Bolzano's in a), so I could prove that there's a point where the derivative is 0 in that point, so I will have something like $0=f'(\alpha (c))\cdot \alpha ' (c)$, but this leads me to nothing.

So I managed to do something with the a) but I'm not sure at all if my attempt is correct, and I can't even start the b). I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: When you write the symbol "/", do you mean for use to read it as "such that"? If so, it would be much better to just write the words "such that." You can get away with writing things more cryptically on a blackboard during a lecture because you can say the words as you write the symbols, but here we have only what you wrote. In many cases words are better than math symbols. (By the way, when you actually _need_ a symbol for "such that", as in $\{x\mid x<1\},$ you can write it `\mid`.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll fix that. English is not my first language and I just don't know how to properly translate some phrases in a proof, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write out the definition of a limit as it applies to
$\lim _{n\to \infty}f(Q_{n})=+\infty$, it's something equivalent to

> For any $M\in \mathbb R$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > n_0$ then $f(Q_n) > M.$

I say "equivalent to" because your textbook might put it in a slightly different form. I would recommend to use the textbook's form rather than mine, but try to apply the same ideas.

You don't necessarily need to quote the definition in the proof. You can take some steps to apply it to your particular problem before writing it in the proof, but it helps if you don't skip too many steps. And if you get confused, you can write *all* the steps on a piece of scrap paper in as much detail as you need to sort them out before writing this part of the proof.

So you might choose to let $M = 0$ for your application. I think I might write the result into the proof before going any farther:

> Then there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > n_0$ then $f(Q_n) > 0.$

Now you want a particular $n$ as described in the sentence above. An easy way is to let $n_1 = n_0+1,$ and now you know such a number $n_1$ exists (because $n_0$ exists) and you know something about $f(Q_{n_1}).$

Unless your definition of limit has "$n \geq n_0$" where I wrote "$n > n_0$", however, you won't get much use out of $f(Q_{n_0}).$

Also, so far none of this has anything to do with $f$ being continuous. It's simply and purely about the definition of a limit.

Next you set up $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
but I think you want $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$, since $(1,2)$ is not in $\mathbb R.$

I think later you meant to say $g(1) > 0$ rather than $g(1) > 1.$ A typo?

If you've already done Bolzano's theorem, you don't need to repeat its proof. Just state the theorem, show you have certain things corresponding to its premises, and then write the corresponding conclusion.
When you get more fluent with proof-writing you won't even have to state the theorem literally, just write something like, "Then by Bolzano's theorem, ... ."

For part b), the proof depends on what tools you've already developed.
But I would probably look at $(P-Q) \cdot \nabla f(\alpha(t))$ as a function of $t.$

I would like to point out that it can happen in part b) that the only way for $\nabla f$ to be "orthogonal" to $P-Q$ is when $\nabla f(x,y) = 0.$
For example, consider the function $f(x,y) = x^2 - 4$ and the points
$P = (2,0)$ and $Q = (-2,0).$

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been really helpful.
`"but I think you want $α:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}^2$, since $(1,2)$ is not in $\mathbb{R}$."`, yes it was a typo, i just forgot to add the`^2`, I will correct it.
`"I think later you meant to say g(1)>0 rather than g(1)>1. A typo?"` yes lol sorry
`"If you've already done Bolzano's theorem, you don't need to repeat its proof. "` this is an exam exercise and some professors just want you to prove everything so I have to practice proving it just in case he wants it that way.
About the b), I kinda thought it like that, but I can't actually realize _why_ [...]

Comment: [...] for every P and Q such that $f(P)=f(Q)$ (it has to necessary be equal to 0? or is that just a condition in this exercise?) the vector $P-Q$ is orthogonal to $\nabla f(x,y)=0$, I mean, in some way I can't really understand the concept of subtracting two points of the domain, and why the subtraction of them has to behave that way. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Still struggling with the b). Also if $\nabla f(R)=0$ then i find even harder to prove that it's orthogonal to $P-Q$, because as far as I know to prove that two vectors are orthogonal you have to prove that the dot product between them is equal to 0, and both of them have to be different to 0, but this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: My interpretation of $P-Q$ as a vector is that it is a vector in the same direction as the direction from $Q$ to $P$ and the same length as the distance from $Q$ to $P$. I think this is a typical notation but to be fair it really should have been defined rather than just assumed.

Comment: Usually "orthogonal vector" means to me exactly what you said. Strictly speaking, I don't think part b) is really a correct thing to prove, because I think it really should say that $\nabla f$ is either orthogonal to $P-Q$ **or is zero**. In my last paragraph I have a concrete example of choices of $f$, $P,$ and $Q$ for which $\nabla f$ is never a non-zero vector orthogonal to $P-Q,$ though it is zero at some points.

Comment: Sorry english is not my first language, I didn't mean that I don't understand what P-Q means, but that I don't understand the point of proving that, just like you said "I don't think b) is reallly a correct thing to prove". I tried also thinking it in this way: I want to prove that $\langle \nabla f(R), P-Q \rangle = 0$, or what it's the same $\langle \left( \frac{\partial f(R)}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f(R)}{\partial y} \right), (P_x-Q_x,P_y-Q_y) \rangle = 0$. And both $\frac{\partial f(R)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f(R)}{\partial y}$ that satisfies this equation must exist [...]

Comment: [...] because f is $C^1$. Another thing that I thought it could work is something like the unit vector $\frac{P-Q}{||P-Q||}$ has the same direction than P-Q, therefore if $\nabla f(R)$ is orthogonal to P-Q, it's also orthogonal to $\frac{P-Q}{||P-Q||}$. So if I could prove that the limit $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(R+t\left(\frac{P-Q}{||P-Q||}\right))-f(R)}{t\left(\frac{P-Q}{||P-Q||}\right)}$ exists then $\nabla f(R)$ is orthogonal to P-Q, but it seems pretty much the same than proving the other way.

Comment: I think you are right about what you can prove. And actually making a unit vector in the direction of $P-Q$ is useful because once you have such a vector, call it $\hat v$, then $\langle \nabla f(R), \hat v \rangle$ is a directional derivative, and if you set up a function $\beta:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ that maps $[0,1]$ linearly to the line segment from $Q$ to $P$, the directional derivative is also the derivative of $f(\beta(t))$ and you can use Rolle's Theorem as you thought. But there are a lot of details in there, so hopefully I didn't miss something.

Comment: I tried to do something like that at first but I thought I was doing it wrong so I didn't manage to finish it. Now that you agree with me I kinda had a boost it confidence and I tried it again but I'm not really sure if it is correct. I still find it kinda forced in some way. But here we go. I take a continuous function $\beta : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\beta (0)=P$ and $\beta (1)=Q$, and then define another function $g : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(t)=f(\beta (t))$. This function is continuous in [0,1] and derivable in (0,1) for the chain rule. Then I [...]

Comment: can apply Rolle's theorem, which tells me that there's a point c such that $g'(c)=0$. Since g is not a constant function I know for Weierstrass theorem that the function will reach at least a maximum or a minimum in the interior of the set. Let's call this maximum or minimum c. Then, for Fermat's theorem $g'(c)=0=\nabla f(\beta (c)) \cdot \beta '(c)$ (now it's when I start struggling with the proof). Now let's define $\beta '(c)=P-Q$ (I don't think I can do this, but I'm not able to come across with another thing). Then $0=\nabla f(\beta (c)) \cdot (P-Q)$, let's call $R=\beta (c)$. QED.

Comment: I was thinking essentially the same thing. You cannot just define $\beta'(c)=P-Q,$ but instead it is something that can be proved. You might start with a definition of $\beta$ like $\beta(t)=Q+t(P-Q).$ I think this meets all your other needs and you can just differentiate with respect to $t$.

Comment: Just one note, for $P-Q$ you want $0\mapsto Q$ and $1\mapsto P.$ it is a bad thing about the $P-Q$ notation that it looks like the vector should be in the opposite direction.